# Why is my blueman indicator missing?

Tags: bluetooth, indicator, applet, blueman

I have just fresh installed Ubuntu 14.10. I want to use blueman instead of bluez, so I have disabled bluez in upper bar, by using option in system settings. However, blueman icon does not appear in the system tray. I have restarted computer several times, and blueman indicator should start with system, it is in start up applications. Any ideas? Thank you!

[image]

Edit1: If I launch it with the terminal(/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet), I get:

```
Loading configuration plugins
blueman-applet version 1.23 starting
There is an instance already running
```

**ps -aux | grep -i blueman** shows:

```
dusan     3806  0.0  0.5 565924 43536 ?        Sl   11:44   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet
dusan    11266  0.0  0.0  15136  2492 pts/0    S+   11:48   0:00 grep --color=auto -i blueman
```

Comment: what does `ps -aux | grep -i blueman` show?
what if you manually launch it from terminal with `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet` ?

Comment: what if you enable bluetooth in the upper bar in system settings? do you see two icons (one for bluez and one for blueman)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to re-enable systray through a patch. Try running the following commands to install the appropriate patch for Ubuntu 14.10

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-utopic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then, restart Unity by pressing ALT + F2 and entering "unity" or by logging out. The PPA should then automatically whitelist all applications and show them on the tray.

For more information :

> http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html