# Audio bug fixes for Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: sound

After installing 14.04.2 LTS just this week I find a few small but somewhat annoying issues, such as no speaker audio, only head phones.

How or what should I do to fix these items?

```
Lenovo-Yoga-2-Pro Kernel: 4.8.0-52-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Unity 7.4.0 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3)
           Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: LENOVO product: 20266 v: Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Yoga2 v: 31900056WIN
           Bios: LENOVO v: 76CN43WW date: 03/30/2015
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-4510U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 10375
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 2295 MHz 2: 2000 MHz 3: 2540 MHz
           4: 2432 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
           bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 3200x1800@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.8.0-52-generic
Network:   Card: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 512.1GB (10.0% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SAMSUNG_MZMTE512 size: 512.1GB temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 235G used: 41G (18%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.50GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 56.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 226 Uptime: 54 min Memory: 1725.0/7895.1MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Comment: It does not look that you installed 14.04.2. It looks more like 16.04.2.

Comment: Please ask a separate question regarding each problem you have.

Comment: I took the liberty to revert your edit. Ask Ubuntu is no forum and we'd like to keep questions and answers neatly separated. If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) (once it is reopened) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because OP found a solution (albeit I reverted the edit that added the answer to the question body).

Comment: @David Foerster, thank you for your advice my apologies I'm not familiar with the format in this site, could you please restructure this so it meets the requirements, or advise as to how I should correct the issues. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Found while trying to solve another problem with Bluetooth this fixed both issues, I'm not sure why or how.

[FIX](https://github.com/dlech/ev3dev.github.io/commit/58f60076ed66f58d4e068c039d30f7546b7e7a0b)

The actual hardware (sensor or other device).
 * Technical documentation on the hardware that explains the low level
   communications (or circuit diagram for analog sensors).
-* A computer or virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04. (Other Linux distros are
+* A computer or virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04. (Other Linux distros are
   OK, but this is what we officially support.)
 * An EV3 serial port adapter like [mindsensors.com EV3 Console Adapter] or
   [make your own][ev3-creating-a-console-cable].
64 docs/tutorials/connecting-to-the-internet-via-bluetooth.md
@@ -231,7 +231,7 @@ If you are using an older version, please upgrade.
             robot@ev3dev:~$

- {: tab="Ubuntu"}{% include icon.html type="info" %}

  - These instructions were written using Ubuntu 14.04 and the default desktop.
  - These instructions were written using Ubuntu 16.04 and the default desktop.
    It should work for other versions of Ubuntu, derivatives of Ubuntu and
    desktop environments as well.
    {: .alert .alert-info}
    @@ -241,52 +241,46 @@ If you are using an older version, please upgrade.

    ```
     sudo apt-get install blueman
    ```
  - {% include icon.html type="info" %}
  - The default Ubuntu Unity desktop does not show the `blueman-applet`
  - icon in the notification tray. If you would like to enable this, please see
  - [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/574460/blueman-indicator-missing){: .alert-link}.
  - {: .alert .alert-info}
  - 2. Run the Blueman *Bluetooth Manager*.
  - 2. Run `blueman-services` from a terminal. (Or if you have the tray icon,
  - right-click on it and choose "Local Services...")
  - {% include screenshot.html source="/images/ubuntu/16.04/blueman-manager-icon.png" %}
  - 3. Go to network. Ensure you activated *Network Access Point (NAP)* and
  - *dnsmasq*. For *PAN support* choose *NetworkManager* but for *DUN-support*
  - choose *Blueman*. Then click *Close*.
  - 3. On the *View* menu, select *Local Services...*.
  - {% include screenshot.html source="/images/ubuntu/15.10/blueman-services-network.png" %}
  - {% include screenshot.html source="/images/ubuntu/16.04/blueman-manager-view-local-services.png" %}
  - {% include icon.html type="info" %}
  - If your EV3 is already paired, you will need to remove it and pair it
  - again so that it will see the new network service.
  - {: .alert .alert-info}
  - 4. Go to *Network*. Check *Network Access Point (NAP)* and *dnsmasq*. Change
  - the IP address to `10.42.0.1` (this matches the old default from Ubuntu
  - 14.04). For *PAN support* choose *NetworkManager*. *DUN-support* does not
  - matter, we are not using it. Then click *Apply* and *Close*.
  - 4. On the EV3, first verify that Bluetooth is powered on. In brickman,
  - {% include screenshot.html source="/images/ubuntu/16.04/blueman-services-network.png" %}
    +
    +
  - 5. On the EV3, first verify that Bluetooth is powered on. In brickman,
       open the *Wireless and Networks* menu and select *Bluetooth*. Make sure the
       *Powered* checkbox is checked. The Bluetooth icon next to the battery in the
       status bar also indicates that Bluetooth is powered on.

       {% include screenshot.html source="/images/brickman/bluetooth-powered-visible-no-devices.png" %}

### -    5.  On your host computer, make sure Bluetooth is powered on and visible.

### -        {% include screenshot.html source="/images/ubuntu/15.10/bluetooth-app-indicator-powered-visible.png" %}

- 6. On the EV3, select *Start Scan* on the *Bluetooth* menu. It should find your

     ### -        computer.
- {% include screenshot.html source="/images/brickman/bluetooth-powered-my-computer.png" %}
- 5. Back on your host computer, Click *Search* (1) to search for your EV3. Once
- it appears, click the pair icon (2) to pair it. You will be asked to confirm
- on both the EV3 and the host computer. Finally, after you have paired,
- click the trust icon (3) to allow the EV3 to automatically connect.
- 7. Select your computer from the menu and then select the *Pair* button.
- {% include screenshot.html source="/images/ubuntu/16.04/blueman-manager-search-pair-trust.png" %}

### -        {% include screenshot.html source="/images/brickman/bluetooth-my-computer-not-paired.png" %}

- 8. Confirm or enter the passkey if requested. The exact behavior here will
- depend on the Bluetooth adapter on your host computer.
- {% include screenshot.html source="/images/ubuntu/16.04/bluetooth-pairing-request.png" %}

  ```
   {% include screenshot.html source="/images/brickman/bluetooth-confirm-passkey.png" %}
  ```
- 12. You should have a *Network Connection* button. Select it to
- {% include icon.html type="info" %}
- If your EV3 is already paired, you will need to remove it and pair it
- again so that it will see the new network service.
- {: .alert .alert-info}
  +
- 6. You should now have a *Network Connection* button. Select it to
      open the network connection settings. (You can also find the connection
      in *Wireless and Networks > All Network Connections*.)

@@ -298,17 +292,17 @@ If you are using an older version, please upgrade.
         *Connect* on the *Network Connection* screen below instead.
         {: .alert .alert-info}

- 13. Select *Connect* here. You can also check the box for *Connect automatically*.
- 7. Select *Connect* here. You can also check the box for *Connect automatically*.
      This way you don't have to connect manually after you reboot.

     {% include screenshot.html source="/images/brickman/networking-my-computer-0-connect-selected.png" %}
- 14. *State* should change to *Online* to indicate that the EV3 has an Internet
- 8. *State* should change to *Online* to indicate that the EV3 has an Internet
      connection.

     {% include screenshot.html source="/images/brickman/networking-my-computer-0-disconnect-selected-online.png" %}
- 11. Now we are going to connect to the EV3 using ssh. In a terminal, run the
- 9. Now we are going to connect to the EV3 using ssh. In a terminal, run the
      following command.

     ```
      ssh robot@ev3dev.local
     ```

     @@ -329,7 +323,7 @@ If you are using an older version, please upgrade.
- 12. Enter your password when prompted. The default password is `maker`.
- 10. Enter your password when prompted. The default password is `maker`.